# How to add "Drag to install!"/Install Icon in eclipse market place?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-marketplace

I have 2 eclipse plugins on marketplace:

- http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pextools
- http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/508788
  However I am not able to add the "Install" icon, [image]  to my project like its there for this plugin
  .
- https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subclipse

Googling did not help. Please guide...

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a little bit of toying around, I finally got it.
Its not very obvious at the first glance and wish the people at marketplace make a note of this.
These are the steps:

1. After logging in and going to your project, click on **Edit** tab.
2. Go to the ***Feature IDs*** section and enter your feature id.
3. You can figure out your feature id by going through [**this**](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/feature-how-to) link
4. After you save, the **"Install"** button will appear. Make sure you test it out!